# Is there a substitute for Dzira (Georgian Caraway) in Khinkali?

Tags: dumplings

I have been looking up Khinkali recipes online and from my research it would seem that authentic Georgian Khinkali make use of a spice called dzira. Since it is sometimes referred to as "Georgian Caraway" I am wondering if I can substitute regular caraway for it?

I live in New York City, and I have never seen Dzira in any of the spice shops that I have visited.

Comment: Dzira.... Jeera :) ... so it likely is a type of CUMIN not caraway. A quick web search suggest it is not normal cumin either. Have you checked whether black cumin or ajwain could be a match?

Comment: Are you sure it is not just caraway? Lke rackandboneman, I suspected cumin first, then went searching, and the most interesting thing I found was this: [A linguistic explanation of the word dzira in Georgian](https://peripateticpedagogue.wordpress.com/2012/09/15/open-questions-regarding-cumin/)

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Well after reading the article, it does seem to be likely. The problem for me is of course that I keep finding contradictory sources on the internet. However, an etymology blog does seem more trust-able than other sources. I suppose I could try to make a few dumplings with Caraway, a few with Cumin, and see which ones seem to remind me most of the ones that I have tried in high end restaurants.

Comment: I have exactly zero experience with Georgian cuisine, so can't help there, but indeed: Give it a go!